# Bokeh panel not printed when is inside an if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am using Bokeh to print out a multiple sequence alignment. So far, it has worked perfectly. For example:

```
[*Previous code that was not included*]
aln = AlignIO.read(alignment_file,'fasta')
p = view_alignment(aln, plot_width=900)
pn.pane.Bokeh(p)
```

[image]

However, I am trying to introduce an if-statement as it follows, it simply does not print anything:

```
if result == 1:
    print('The gen you selected does not have any ortholog.')
else:
    aln = AlignIO.read(alignment_file,'fasta')
    p = view_alignment(aln, plot_width=900)
    pn.pane.Bokeh(p)
```

I have introduced a print('Check if it works') inside the else part of the if-statement and it does print it. But the bokeh panel doesn't get printed.

I am using JupyterLab to try these things version 3.2.1. Not entirely sure what's happening. The reason why I am including this if-statement is to filter the gen that do not have any orthologs. Otherwise, it would print simply one sequence and it does not make sense for what I am trying to achieve here.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

I imported show from bokeh.io.

```
from bokeh.io import show
```

Finally simply call the graph that it was already form as:

```
show(p)
```

Everything is working as it should now!